# Django - fetch coinmarketcap pro api results in "string indices must be integers"

Tags: python, json, django, api

i'm currently trying to fetch the exchanges rates of coinmarketcap on there free "pro" api but for some reason i get the following error:
"string indices must be integers"

```
def get_exchange_rate():
    api_url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'
    parameters = {
        'start':'1',
        'limit':'1000',
        'convert':'USD'
    }
    headers = {
        'Accepts': 'application/json',
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': '7D3728e3-RANDOM-9282-1244',
    }
    session = Session()
    session.headers.update(headers)
    try:
        CryptoPrices.objects.all().delete()
        data = session.get(api_url, params=parameters)
        exchange_rates = data.json()
        for exchange_rate in exchange_rates:
            CryptoPrices.objects.update_or_create(
                key=exchange_rate['slug'],
                defaults={
                    "symbol": exchange_rate['symbol'],
                    "rank": int(exchange_rate['cmc_rank']),
                    "market_cap_usd": round(float(exchange_rate['market_cap']), 3),
                    "volume_usd_24h": round(float(exchange_rate['volume_24h']), 3),
                    "value": round(float(exchange_rate['price']), 3),
                })
        logger.info("Exchange rate(s) updated successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        logger.info(str("Something went wrong))
```

This is what the API output looks like if i fetch it with curl:

> curl -H "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: 7D3728e3-RANDOM-9282-1244" -H
>   "Accept: application/json" -d "start=1&limit=1000" -G
>   https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest

```
{
    "status": {
        "timestamp": "2019-09-17T11:11:22.727Z",
        "error_code": 0,
        "error_message": null,
        "elapsed": 239,
        "credit_count": 12
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "symbol": "BTC",
            "slug": "bitcoin",
            "num_market_pairs": 8040,
            "date_added": "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
            "tags": [
                "mineable"
            ],
            "max_supply": 21000000,
            "circulating_supply": 17940975,
            "total_supply": 17940975,
            "platform": null,
            "cmc_rank": 1,
            "last_updated": "2019-09-17T11:10:34.000Z",
            "quote": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 10223.8334901,
                    "volume_24h": 15061189990.6449,
                    "percent_change_1h": 0.14997,
                    "percent_change_24h": -1.11433,
                    "percent_change_7d": -0.495979,
                    "market_cap": 183425541050.04684,
                    "last_updated": "2019-09-17T11:10:34.000Z"
                }
            }
        },
...
```

I didn't worked a lot with JSON API parsing befor, i would be thankful for a good hint. Beside, is there anything else i have to check on at the json data structure? To me it looks like that: "quote": { and "USD": { includes data that is wrapped within the "{", do i need to access the data at my parsing differently?

Comment: add the error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Response json is dict of data and status.

So, Before iterating over the data list first fetch it form response dict.

Right after loading json place this line and then try.

```
exchange_rates = data.json()
exchange_rates = exchange_rates.get('data', [])
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue like this:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/45')), name="Update Crypto Rates", ignore_result=True)
def get_exchange_rate():
    api_url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'
    parameters = {
        'start':'1',
        'limit':'1000',
        'convert':'USD'
    }
    headers = {
        'Accepts': 'application/json',
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': '7D3728e3-RANDOM-9282-1244',
    }
    session = Session()
    session.headers.update(headers)
    try:
        CryptoPrices.objects.all().delete()
        response = session.get(api_url, params=parameters)
        exchange_rates = response.json()["data"]
        for exchange_rate in exchange_rates:
            CryptoPrices.objects.update_or_create(
                key=exchange_rate['slug'],
                defaults={
                    "symbol": exchange_rate['symbol'],
                    "rank": int(exchange_rate['cmc_rank']),
                    "market_cap_usd": round(float(exchange_rate["quote"]["USD"]["market_cap"]), 3),
                    "volume_usd_24h": round(float(exchange_rate["quote"]["USD"]["volume_24h"] or 0), 3),
                    "value": round(float(exchange_rate["quote"]["USD"]["price"]), 3),
                })
        logger.info("Crypto exchange rate(s) updated successfully.")
    except:
        logger.info(str("Error, please investigate"))
```

It's essentially to use -> "or 0"
as some currencies return 0 or null

models.py

```
    class CryptoPrices(models.Model):
        key = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
        symbol = models.CharField(max_length=15)
        rank = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
        market_cap_usd = models.FloatField(max_length=16)
        volume_usd_24h = models.FloatField(max_length=16)
        value = models.FloatField(max_length=12)
```

(Maybe max_lenght needs to be changed here...)

You can also use the APIv1 of CMC like this (no API key needed):

```
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/45')), name="Update Crypto Rates", gnore_result=True)
def get_exchange_rate():
    api_url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"
    try:
        CryptoPrices.objects.all().delete()
        exchange_rates = requests.get(api_url).json()
        for exchange_rate in exchange_rates:
            CryptoPrices.objects.update_or_create(
                key=exchange_rate['id'],
                defaults={
                    "symbol": exchange_rate['symbol'],
                    "rank": int(exchange_rate['rank']),
                    "market_cap_usd": round(float(exchange_rate['market_cap_usd']), 3),
                    "volume_usd_24h": round(float(exchange_rate['24h_volume_usd']), 3),
                    "value": round(float(exchange_rate['price_usd']), 3),
                })
        logger.info("Crypto exchange rate(s) updated successfully.")
    except:
        logger.info(str("Error, please investigate"))
```

Maybe this answere will help smb too :)